# Barreiras com threads - Output excerto código

Tags: java, thread

Tenho o seguinte excerto de código. Alguém me consegue explicar a seguinte questão?

No `main` quando crio as duas threads, vou para o construtor do `Boat` e noto que dorme um segundo. Porque é que é o `main` que assume esse `sleep` no seu tempo e porque não é cada thread individualmente?

```
public class Boat extends Thread{
private Dock dock;
private long initialTime;

public Boat(String name, Dock dock, long initialTime) throws InterruptedException{
    setName(name);
    this.initialTime = initialTime;
    this.dock = dock;
    sleep(1000);
}

@Override
public void run(){
    dock.enter();
    try{
        dock.exit();
        sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(getName() + "-" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-initialTime)/1000 + "s");

    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Dock d = new Dock();
    Boat t1 = new Boat("b1", d, sTime);
    Boat t2 = new Boat("b2", d, sTime);
    System.out.println("Start!");
    t1.start();
    sleep(1000);
    t1.interrupt();
    t2.start();
    sleep(1000);
    d.exit();
    t2.join();
    sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Main - Finished " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-sTime)/1000+"s");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há três threads em seu programa, a principal, o `b1` e o `b2`.

A thread principal inicia o programa criando as outras duas. Observe que a thread principal invoca o construtor para o objeto `b1`. O fato de `b1` herdar de `Thread` é irrelavante até este ponto, isso só vai fazer diferença quando o `start()` for chamado. **Até aqui, `b1` é apenas um objeto como outro qualquer.** Assim sendo, quem vai executar o `sleep(1000)` do construtor de `b1` é a thread principal. O mesmo acontece com `b2`.

Somente após esses dois `sleep`s dos construtores é que o `Start!` vai aparecer no console e ele vai iniciar a thread `b1` de verdade. A thread `b1` vai executar o seu método `run()`.

O método `interrupt()` pede para que uma outra thread pare, mas não espera ela parar de fato. Já o método `join()` espera a outra thread parar, mas não pede para que ela pare. Para fazer as duas coisas, você teria que chamar para cada thread `interrupt()` seguido de `join()`. Ocorre que na `b1` você só chama o `interrupt()` e na `b2` você só chama o `join()`. Assim sendo, a thread principal vai pedir para a `b1` parar, mas não vai esperar ela parar, enquanto que não vai pedir a `b2` parar mas vai esperar com que ela pare. Depois disso tudo, a thread principal vai fazer um `sleep(1000)` após esperar o final de `b2`, mas sem garantir que `b1` tenha terminado.

Esse código demonstra que você não deve estar entendendo como funciona o fluxo quando há múltiplas threads. Basicamente, é o seguinte:

1. A thread que começa a executar um método sempre é a mesma que o termina. Não há na linguagem Java nada que permita uma thread começar a executar um método e outra terminá-lo. Isso significa que tudo que está dentro do `main` é executado pela thread principal.
2. Todas as chamadas a métodos e construtores que estão dentro de um outro método executado por uma determinada thread, também serão executados por essa mesma thread. Isso significa que a thread que executa o método `main`, ao invocar o construtor de `Boat`, irá ela mesma executar esse construtor, uma vez que tudo que está dentro do método `main` será executado pela thread principal.
3. Uma thread só é iniciada de fato ao invocar-se o método `start()` e a execução da nova thread inicia no método `run()` correspondente. Isso significa que a thread que executar o construtor não é a mesma que vai estar executando o `run()`. Isso também significa que antes de `start()` ser invocado, o objeto que representa a thread é apenas um objeto Java como qualquer outro sem nada de especial.
4. Observe que uma vez que `start()` e `run()` são métodos diferentes, a regra 2 acima não é violada. A thread principal executa o `start()`, mas quem executa o `run()` é a thread criada.